# GCP Cloud Tasks are defined per project or service?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I'm creating a new service in App Engine Python 3 using a Cloud Task queue. The project already has a service using python 2 and declaring the queues in a `queue.yaml` file.

According with the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/queue-yaml) I can't mix the queue's creation using `queue.yaml` and Cloud Tasks API, so I'll create another yaml file for the new service.

My question is if the new `queue.yaml` will overwrite the existing queues or I can declare distinct queues for each service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The queue.yaml file is global to the project. On app engine you can have only one. If you create a new one and you omit the previous one, the previous will be paused or deleted.

If you use Cloud Task, don't forget to add the existing task queue in the queue.yaml file for preventing the pause or the deletion of the Cloud Task queue.

My recommendation: forget the queue.yaml file and switch to the Cloud Task. queue.yaml file belong to the old version. Deprecated a day. Bet on the future!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since the queues of the python 2 app already declared, I can deploy a new version without `'queue.yaml` and then declare the queues of the new app throught the Cloud Tasks API?

Comment: You can deploy your new version without queue.yaml. (keep your app.yaml, and others optional ones, like cron.yaml). if you do this, the existing queue are kept. and then you can use only Cloud Task. But be sure that you will never deploy again with a queue.yaml file, else strange things will happen!